# any 8 bit fast adder designs

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

so i'm trying to design a CPU and in all my previous designs i have used a cascade adder but i want to try using a fast adder to speed things up. when i search for "8 bit fast adders" all i get is the 4 bit fast adder designs and i don't want to link all the carry ins and outs together so does anyone have a true 8 bit fast adder design. all i want is the diagram, which means only the logic gates(and gate, or gate, etc) no blocks or anything like that. for an 8 bit adder with fast carry no other operations just adding.

Comment: there are multiple adders implementations in the dedicated [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)) page. Pick the one you like.

Comment: that's a pretty cool project, but maybe you'd want to look into how automated design tools implement single-cycle adder. I've had some kind of a look at single-cycle multipliers in my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280673/why-does-hardware-division-take-much-longer-than-multiplication/280695#280695). You probably don't want exactly that architecture (which is FPGA-specific) in your CPU, but really, the complexity of a "fast multiplier" is staggering, and I don't believe you "need" to implement an adder on your own if you'd use any common RTL to describe your CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question what makes an adder "fast" is often a technological one – are you implementing (or simulating it) for ASIC, or some specific FPGA?

In either case, you'll have elementary "building blocks" that you'll "plug together"; it's really not like your usually dealing with "AND" and "OR" components when describing a CPU design.

As an example, take this minimal 8-bit adder Verilog module:

```
module add (clk, a, b, result);
   input clk;
   input [7:0]a;
   input [7:0]b;
   output [15:0]result;
   always @(posedge clk)
     result = a + b;
endmodule // add
```

Implemented for an ICE40 FPGA, it would look like this. Notice that the blocks here **are** the elementary building blocks. There's no AND/OR here – so optimizing an adder for speed with those makes zero sense:

[image: ICE 40]

---

compare that to the more abstract "general" techmap that yosys (which I'm using to generate these trees) generates:

[image: general]

You'll see your AND, XOR, XNOR, NAND "gate" primitives in there, but also things like AOI (and-or-invert) – which the software deems useful, because they might map to something specifically easy and compact to implement on any given architecture, be it an FPGA or ASIC cells.

---

So, generally, it **is** important to understand what logic constitutes a complex operation such as "add". However, as soon as your optimizing that for speed, size, power, you'll have to consider the actual thing that will implement that – be it an ASIC, be it something built from 74xx or be it an FPGA – and a general rule like "this is a fast implementation" cease to exist.

Comment: I actually was looking for more of a non fpga approach so thankyou marcus müller but what would the circuit diagram of the oai or aio or any of those that are in there

Comment: @keco2002 you're missing my point: that depends on what elements you can have in your circuit. In my circuits, I can have AIOs.

Comment: Ah i see, so everyone has ther own sort of design for a fast adder depending on the application?

Comment: Exactly, and very much depending on the technology they use, too!

Comment: ...and the technology vendor knows more about what works well in their technology than you do...