# How to minimize slack for mod in numerical package?

Tags: vhdl, timing-analysis, vhdl-2008

Here is the snippet of the code in VHDL.
I mean this  `IEEE.numeric_std.all`

```vhdl
shift_reg <= b"0011" & std_logic_vector("/" (temp_result, divisor) (3 downto 0));
temp_result <= temp_result mod divisor;
divisor <= divisor / 4d"10";
```

This is what I got from Timing Analysis in Quartus. There is a lot of look up tables for `mod`

[image]

[image]

The reason why I use divisor is that the result should be displayed one by one in LCD. For instance, 365 have to divided into 3, 6 and 5 in `num_array`.

```
-- define the new type for the 6x4 RAM 
type num_array is array (0 to 5) of unsigned (3 downto 0);
 signal my_array                        : num_array:= (others => (others => '0'));
```

Comment: your `shift_reg` seems unused. I don't think `4d"10"` is valid VHDL, but I'm not too used to VHDL anymore, and especially not to VHDL2008. What does `std_logic_vector("/" (temp_result, divisor) (3 downto 0))` do?

Comment: When you use the mod-operator, the synthesis tools create a combinatorial division module, as most (all?) FPGAs do not have any built-in division-module (as they have for multiplication). Combinatorial division modules always have a very deep path from input to output. So you could reduce your clock frequency, or define multicycle paths for the mod-operation, or build your own clocked division module.

Comment: There is multiplying with the multiplicative inverse of 10.

Comment: @greybeard you mean in a binary Galois field? That wouldn't work, would it, 10 not being coprime with 2^n?

Comment: by the way, @kile: what are you trying to build in the larger picture? The module you're building is called `lcd`, but if that means `Lowest Common Denominator`, then it's not clear what the division with 10 has to do there.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am building a calculator for my LCD 16*2 display. I am using DE10 lite which use Intell Max 10 FPPGA. The datasheet for this LCD IC chip could be found here https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf

Comment: cool, @kile! But then: it's getting all a bit easier, because LCDs (and human eyes) are incredibly slow compared to FPGAs. So, instead of using `/` and `mod`, what about a state machine which simply subtracts until the result would get smaller than 0, and then emits the count of subtracting (so, the division) and the remainder (so, `mod`)?

Comment: For human interface speed binary-to-decimal, there's always bit-serial double dabble. Going with a state machine may well end you with an embedded processor.

Comment: @greybeard heh; historically, there's a certain coevolution of desk/pocket calculators and small MCUs, so practically, that wouldn't be absurd at all. Regarding the double-dabble algorithm: Love that, but not convinced it's even more space efficient than just a stupid "binary search for the right multiplier"-division-and-mod algorithm – that "beast" of an FPGA has multiplier blocks.

Comment: @greybeard What do you mean state machine here? I already have implemented state machine in lcd block. Do you mean that I have to do it once again for bit-serial double dabble algorithm?

Comment: @kile  His statement about state machines referred to my proposal to replace your usage of mod and division with a state machine. But: Check wikipedia for [double-dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble); that algorithm is a deeply pipelined, without explicit state-machine, algorithm to convert binary numbers to the decimal digits in BCD.

Comment: Another point is that you don't have timing slack because you're running it on a 50MHz clock. You could probably just add in a clock divider down to 10 or 1 MHz and make this approach work.

Comment: @W5VO I have already used PLL for this clock divider

Comment: My only point is that you don't seem to have a throughput requirement or part of your system that requires 50MHz, or anything close for that matter. If your just trying to implement the function, lower your clock frequency. If you're trying to learn about algorithms and STA, please continue.

Comment: This question (or the comments?) seems to wander from its title to *how to do a VHDL calculator* (and *Why?*). To begin with the title, you have *negative* slack.

Comment: @greybeard Do you mean that I have to change the title for this question?

Comment: I think the title should summarise what you want answered. If that was *How to do a 16 digit calculator in VHDL in general and binary-to-decimal conversion in particular?*, the title should reflect that. If you want to get Quartus not to report an error with minimum change to the existing design (of which you show little enough), just check if the problem was indeed *minimize slack*, 0 being as low as it usefully gets.

Comment: Or at least _edit your question_ to point out that you're doing a calculator that needs to operate at human speed.  You may also want to mention the clock speed you're using, your goals for logic footprint, and **most importantly** the speed you actually need for the computation.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145370/discussion-on-question-by-kile-how-to-minimize-slack-for-mod-in-numerical-packag); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problems with your code

> `temp_result <= temp_result mod divisor;`

That's a bad idea: integer mod is an immensely complex operation.

Unless `divisor` is a power of 2, the combinatorial approach to modulo will be nearly as complex as doing a division.

> `divisor <= divisor / 4d"10";`

same problem; dividing by 10 needs a relatively complex divider with a large combinatorial depth.

## Complexities of integer mod and division

Here's a slightly dated view of the combinatorial implementation of division in yosys targetting a small-cell FPGA (from an [older answer of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/280695/64158)):

([Divide on an ICE40](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marcusmueller/3182ccae22a3e714c351c7768a11b075/raw/3495e6afe5baaca5278ec9148e6fe7ddeec0d46b/divide_ice40_.png)) (warning: ~100 Mpixel image)

[image: Scaled image of the divider]

So, in general, doing division or `mod` just in a combinatorial path like you do here is a pretty bad idea.

You'll want to implement a pipelined modulo, I'd guess. Depending of the relative lengths of `temp_result` and `divisor`, that can be relatively flat, or deep.

## Ways out

Well, you'll notice

1. there's probably quite some overlap between what you need to do to calculate `a mod b` and to calculate `a / b`.
2. there's no easy way out – division is just combinatorial intense. So, we need to trade slack for pipeline depth.

The 2. issue is something you'll be quite familiar with when you look what time it takes for anything but really number-crunching optimized CPUs to divide integers – many processor instruction sets do have some kind of integer divide and integer modulo operations, but they take multiple, often *many*, clock cycles to complete.

So, I'd try to find an existing implementation of pipelined integer division (`mod` is often a side product of that) (for example, on opencores.org), or write a very naive one myself, which doesn't need to have constant throughput.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have to display those decimal number one by one at a time. For example, 365 has to be divided into  an array of numbers [3, 6, 5]. In VHDL, it will look like this.

`-- define the new type for the 6x4 RAM 

    type num_array is array (0 to 5) of unsigned (3 downto 0);

  signal my_array      : num_array:= (others => (others => '0'));`

Comment: @kile excellent! Yeah, I'd just have a state machine counting the times I can subtract 1000 until the result would become negative (which gives you the thousands digit), then take the remainder (your `mod`), use the same state machine to count how many times you can subtract 100 (giving you the hundreds digit), and so on. greybeard recommended a much cooler algorithm under your question, but it's much harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

- Division just takes a lot of steps
- A modulo operation is basically division
- Lots of steps translates into lots of logic, or a state machine
- You're building a calculator, so it doesn't have to respond much faster than a human can see it working.

Typically, in an FPGA design, when you have something complicated to do and you have lots of clock cycles to do it in, then unless you have LUTs to burn you make a state machine that breaks the complicated thing down into simpler steps.

It's the same with discrete logic design.  The end point of this process evolved from the mid 1930's to the late 1940's into general purpose computers.  It's still a viable thing to do inside an FPGA: use a microprocessor block, run some code, do your business.

If I didn't just slap a microprocessor block in there (there's a lot of them, including the Nios straight from Intel) I'd either implement a little 4- or 8-bit one of my own (it's a bucket list thing) or I'd research the various available division algorithms that are out there and that use state machines for a complexity vs. clock-cycle tradeoff.

Successive subtraction (just subtract 10 from your number until it's less than 10) and CORDIC are probably your best bets.  Since you're building a calculator *anyway* you may wish to make a division block, and use it for all your arithmetic needs.

Comment: While you're working on your gizmo, consider that most calculators store numbers internally in binary coded decimal, and often in a form of decimal floating point (i.e., mantissa in BCD and an exponent that's a power of 10).  This is done because the numbers are so tightly coupled to what you're displaying that the extra work in doing all the math in base 10 is paid for by the savings in work when you display results.

Comment: Thank you for the better wording.